# How to exclude index.vue from prerendering so that index.html will be generated in dist folder (NuxtJS)?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I use nuxt generate in my project to prerender some routes and excluding dynamic routes from prerendering in `nuxt.config.js` like so:

```js
generate: {
    exclude: ['/', /^\/user/]
}
```

As you can see I'm excluding `index.vue` ('/'). But it causes nuxt not to generate `index.html` in the dist folder. Although I can serve project locally (`npm run start`), when I deploy project it throws 404 error. How can I solve this?

Comment: What are your `target` and `ssr` values? And where do you host it?

Comment: @kissu ssr: true, target: 'static'. I host it on a VPS.

Comment: Do you mind testing it on app.netlify.com/drop? Should be working so far since the pages should be generated by the JS. Otherwise, you can also try `fallback: true` as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#fallback